# Forcing to wrap every function that throws in Reactor Flux.using

Tags: java, stream, flux, reactive, reactor

Currently I have the following code:

```
    private Flux<String> tailFileManual(Path path) {
      final File file = path.toFile();

      return Flux.using(
            () -> new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)),
            reader -> Flux.create(emitter -> {
                while (true) {
                    final String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    } else if (line.equals("null")) {
                        emitter.complete();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        emitter.next(line);
                    }
                }
            }),
            BufferedReader::close
    );
}
```

Running with latest reactor-core (3.1.7), java complains that I have to wrap every thrown type (in this example `IOException`) with try-catch. Now this code runs as it in `rx-java2` using `Flowable.using`, but for some reason `Reactor` is forcing me to manually wrap every possible thrown error in try-catch, making this code **verbose**... Is there something I'm missing?

I don't want to wrap `FileReader`, `Thread.sleep` and `BufferedReader::close` with try-catch, thus missing the whole point of short lambda expressions

Comment: `using` takes a `Consumer<? super D> resourceCleanup` which cannot throw an `Exception` - this is the same problem as any other exception handling in lambdas.

Comment: This exact same code (with `Flux` converted to `Flowable`) works in `rx-java2` as is. Any explanations why?

Comment: It's not the same code, the [method](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#using-java.util.concurrent.Callable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-) takes a [`io.reactivex.functions.Consumer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Consumer.html) which `throws Exception`.